# shell script to use condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to check the status of an application if it's running or not.
For that I have written a below script however being a newbie I am not sure how can I use condition  here such that if "process(pid) is running and URL is accessible then only Application is running OK".

code:

```
#!/bin/bash


#Check: for java connector service
echo "Checking health of java connectors"
PID=$(ps -ef | grep test-core | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
if [ -n "$PID" ]; then
echo "INFO: Java connector service is running"
else

echo "WARNING: Java connector service is not running"
fi

#Check for UI status

status="$(curl -Is http://172.217.23.16/application/authenticate | head -1)"
validate=( $status )
if [ ${validate[-2]} == "200" ]; then
  echo "INFO: Application URL is up and running"
else
  echo "WARNING: Application URL is NOT RESPONDING"
fi
```

I am looking for something like if cond1 && cond2 satisfies then "Application is running OK".

A guidance here would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Enter your script on https://www.shellcheck.net/. It will show some basic tips and warnings.

Comment: Well, you already **do** have such a script. It is not clear from your question, in what respect you are not satisfied with your solution.

Comment: @user1934428 I am looking for solution where if both the condition satisfies then only script should say "Application is running". I am not quite aware how can i use if [cond1 && cond2 ] block to check the status of app.

Comment: `grep | awk` is an anti-pattern.  Instead of `grep test-core | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`, you can simply write `awk '/test-core/ && ! /grep/ {print $2}'`

Comment: Stop thinking of "conditions".  The `if` syntax is `if cmd; then`.  If the command succeeds, then do something.  You can use boolean operators: `if cmd1 && cmd2; then ...`

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already calculated the values of `PID` and `validate`, you can combine the tests of your current code into a single one, by doing

```
if [[ -n $PID && ${validate[-2]} == 200 ]]
then
   ...
fi
```